# AJAX, PHP, CodeIgniter - Can't get value from action?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an action.

```
<div class="options">
   <div class="grid-list">
      <a id="grid" class="grid curent" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Grid"><span>img</span></a>
      <a id="list" class="list" href="javascript:void(0)" title="List"><span>img</span></a>
    </div><!-- .grid-list -->
</div><!-- .options -->
```

When I click a tag, only **beforeSend (ajax)** works.

Comment: Include the `error` or the `fail` functions... Look's like it is throwing an error

Comment: do you see any error in console for Ajax ..?

Comment: I can't see any error because the browser doesn't display any error. This is my project https://www.box.com/files/0/f/950402871/1/f_8789300133 (2.6 MB)

Comment: Post the ajax code here.

Comment: @techie_28 I posted the code ajax above, in the first picture.

Comment: I was talking of the the jQuery ajax handler that you have written..which has the beforeSend and other params.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your idea. I just started with ajax. Could you download my code? https://www.box.com/files/0/f/950402871/1/f_8789300133

Comment: Please open Chrome, and let the ajax run. Right click, "Inspect element" then check the console for errors. Furthermore, click the Network tab to see the response object, which might list any PHP errors or other errors. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Firebug for Firefox works great also for finding errors and seeing what response was sent back.

Comment: Hi! I found an error, I feel it is very strange. I named method in controller is group_state, if I rename it's groupstate or group or state then ajax works.

Comment: It's better to paste the code as post code block than as an image, so we'll reproduce the code as reply easily.

Comment: @WildanMuhlis I'm so sorry! I can't post all my code because I get an error "it looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in your PHP *function*

`$view_type=$_POST['viewType']`;

Answer (score 1):

first in url use your base_url in ajax request, define base_url in you config. 
in controller use $view_type = $this->input->post('viewType')